# Refresh content of contenteditable div in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm now working on a project that I want to use contenteditable div.

I have a parent component and child component that has contenteditable div.
I pass jsx object as a prop to child and the div renders that prop.

```
class Parent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        content: <div></div>
     }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     this.setState({
        content: <div>Hello World</div>
     })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        content={this.state.content}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends PureCompoenent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        contentEditable="true"
      >
         {this.props.content}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The code above is just a brief overview of my code.

When I type nothing in child component, and pass the props, then it shows 'Hello World'. This is what I expected.

But if I type something like 'Hi', and pass the props, it should render only 'Hello World', but in fact it shows, 'Hello World\nHi'.

Comment: not getting since you made `contentEditable=true`, so if you type any thing it will come, you dont want to change the text ??

Comment: to be more specific, if I write some code in child component, then the parent analyze and return the result to the child. So once I finish writing code, then click a button, then parent return highlighted text to child.

Comment: we can assume that 'Hello World' is the result I want to show in Child. but below 'Hello World', I always see that the codes I typed before, original codes should be cleared and only the result should show